# Using Sqlite3 with visual C++ 2003

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to use sqlite3 on a program written by C++ 2003.
I have downloaded sqlite-amalgamation-3360000.zip from download page and add sqlite3.h to header files, shell.c & sqlite3.c to resources file.
then I write a simple code in test.cpp to test the connection:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    sqlite3 *db;

    sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &db);


    return 0;
}
```

however when I compiled it always show error:
sqlite3.c(27474): error C2692: '_ReadWriteBarrier' : fully prototyped functions required in C compiler with the '/clr' option

I dont know what I did wrong. Please can someone help?

Comment: You may need an old version of sqlite to support such an old compiler.

Comment: thanks. what version you would recommend?

Comment: Remove /clr compiler option?

Comment: I recommend upgrading to a current compiler, like **Visual Studio 2019**, rather than downgrading to an ancient compiler like **Visual Studio .NET 2003**.

Comment: @Eljay I cant cause it is run on an old machine which cant be migrated to new version anymore.

Comment: In that case, I concur with S.M. and second the removal of `/clr` compiler option.  Is there any reason you'd want that option?

Comment: @Eljay I just cant find that option common language runtime support on C++ 2003 :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where that project flag which controls / maps-to `/clr` is located in VS2003.

Answer (score 2):

`_ReadWriteBarrier` is a [compiler intrinsic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readwritebarrier?view=msvc-160): the compiler is programmed to handle it specially. This is declared in the `intrin.h` header file.

From `sqlite3.c`:

```
/*
** Make sure that the compiler intrinsics we desire are enabled when
** compiling with an appropriate version of MSVC unless prevented by
** the SQLITE_DISABLE_INTRINSIC define.
*/
#if !defined(SQLITE_DISABLE_INTRINSIC)
#  if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER>=1400
#    if !defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#      include <intrin.h>
#      pragma intrinsic(_byteswap_ushort)
#      pragma intrinsic(_byteswap_ulong)
#      pragma intrinsic(_byteswap_uint64)
#      pragma intrinsic(_ReadWriteBarrier)
#    else
#      include <cmnintrin.h>
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

Since you are compiling on an ancient version of MSVC, I suggest disabling this by defining the `SQLITE_DISABLE_INTRINSIC` preprocessor symbol.

Comment: Botje : I think it compiled after I set SQLITE_DISABLE_INTRINSIC a value but when I run the exe file it got a error pop up: JIT Debugging: PID is invalid

Comment: No idea. I only use latest versions of IDEs.